# Is .Net framework enough to run OLEDB based applications?

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

Does OLEDB need any installation other than .NET framework? Do i need to install anything on the target machine (except .NET framework)?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Connect to a particular database??

Comment: i use it to import excel files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET has supported OLEDB through ADO.NET since day one.